# hello.myfonts.net takes long time to load using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

When running some Selenium C# Automation scripts using either the Chrome WebDriver or Gecko/FireFox WebDriver, intermittently the webpage under test will show the message "Waiting for hello.myfonts.net..." and take a long time to load and timeout the scripts. I have a 2min page load timeout.
Looking in the dev tools I can see it it trying to d/load a template from here "https://hello.myfonts.net/count/270fa6", a Stylesheet of around 480 bytes.
Opening the webpage manually always works fine, but I keep getting this issue when running through a WebDriver.
Any ideas?

Comment: I also get this issue, only with fonts from this supplier, I suspect their servers/code aren't up to acting as a CDN and are causing issues or crashing out when attempting to authenticate.